# How can I enable a notification that a pop-up has been blocked in Safari?

Tags: safari

**QUESTION**: Just wondering how to **enable** an alert message notifying me that a pop-up has been blocked?

I know Firefox has that feature(and other related pop-up options), but I don't use Firefox... also preferably avoid 3rd party apps.

I have Safari 5.1 on Mac OS X 10.6.8.

Comment: I was just wondering the same thing.

Comment: So you're looking for what amounts to a second switch: silently block pop-ups / noisily block pop-ups ? (just looking to understand what the notification might be)

Comment: @bmike In Chrome and other browsers, you are alerted to the blocking of a popup by an audio alert and an icon. As far as I can see, no alert is given in Safari. Jon would like to enable such an alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Better Pop Up Blocker](http://optimalcycling.com/other-projects/better-pop-up-blocker/safari/) does trigger an alert in Safari when a popup is locked.

And it also improves the effectiveness of Safari's blocking.

But - the alert behaviour does not work in Lion! Snow Leopard only. If the dev updates it for Lion it should do what you request.

Comment: OP specified 10.6.8 but nice call out on lion issues

Comment: Thanks! This does the job, specifically: Unchecking `Window targets (Checking this forces pages to load in the same tab)`. I was going to wait until all the bugs are out of Lion anyway.